# Can I show a confirmation when i click a Icon?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show a confirmation popup when a person clicks on the icon (i tag). The icon is DELETE icon, so once the user clicks on it, I want to show the confirmation if person really wants to delete the data. Once confirmed, I want to proceed further.

```
<td>
    <a
        href="source.php?admin_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&username=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username']; ?>"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="top"
        title="Delete"
    >
        {" "}
        <i id="Del" class="mdi mdi-close"></i>{" "}
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617583/how-add-confirmation-box-in-php-before-deleting/45468719

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `confirm` function that makes a window alert with 2 options - `ok` and `cancel`. We can check using `if` statements that what was clicked. If `ok` was clicked, the function returns `true` else it returns `false`.

So, you can copy this javascript code -

```js
const deleteIcon = document.getElementById("del");
deleteIcon.addEventListener("click",() => { 
   const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed? ");
   if(confirmVar){
        //stuff that happens after pressing ok
   }else{
        //stuff that happens after pressing cancel
   }
})
```

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: yup it is the best solution.

Comment: Hello there is just one issue guys. When I click cancel it also delete.

Comment: See, what will happen after cancel should be given in the `else` part and what will happen if `OK` is clicked, should be in the `if` part

Comment: Hello I can't still fix it. The else part return statement is false that's what I write there. Pls help

Comment: Here is the code @Aviral.

    const deleteIcon = document.getElementById("del");
deleteIcon.addEventListener("click",(e) => { 
   const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed? ");
   if(confirmVar){
        return true;
   }else{
        return false;
   }
   
})

Comment: Okay so when you click cancel then also it returns true?

Comment: @Aviral yes it is. I'm still stuck there haha I tried to find ways but still, it always delete when I click cancel.

Comment: I don't think that should happen maybe you were doing something with the PHP, I recommend you to ask another question regarding this because i don't know PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var r = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Original sample link: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm2)

Comment: But he's looking for a confirmation box on icon click, it would be best if you could add a code that has the icon button too.

Comment: i have edited my answer. This is so basic. Hope help him as beginner

Comment: Yes, now it looks perfect.